# Unexpected horizontal scroll in the page with barecss

Tags: html, css, layout, browser, less

I am testing this classless framework [barecss](http://barecss.com/), I know it's quite outdated (2016) but I like its simplicity (the demo website seems down but there is the same bug [here](https://microsymfony.ovh/)).

I started to test it, then I realized there was an unexpected horizontal scroll bar, which seemed useless as there is no content in this area:

[image]

There is a line, in the header, when I scroll:

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footer has a `before` element that has `width: 102vw;`. Change that to `100vw` and the scrollbar is gone.

Comment: Interesting. That's weird, with 100vm, I still have a scroll bar, but the scrollable area is indeed smaller. The scroll bar only totally disappears with `99vw` (firefox with full window).